# how to create mongoose connection when testing with gulp mocha

Tags: mongoose, gulp, mocha.js

I want to make a gulp task to run all my tests with mocha with one single command.
(My test need to connection to DB with mongoose)

Then I got this error:

`{ [Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.] state: 1 }`

After some research, I found this post:
 [Mongoose Trying to open unclosed connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712226/mongoose-trying-to-open-unclosed-connection)

It said I should use `createConnection()` instead of 'connect()`.

Here is the question now:

*How could I use `before` and `after` for the test, and how could I call `done` after db connected before go through each test cases?*

Comment: Are you running the `mongoose.connect()` command more than once, even across multiple test scripts? You should only ever need to execute the `connect` command one time.

Comment: Yes, I run them in each test spec. The reason I did this is that I want to make it possible that I also can run each test spec separately while I can run them all in one time. If I can run `mongoose.connect() ` only once run each run, I think I need to work on some gulp script to make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('mocha', function () {
  var testFile = argv['f'];
  var fullPaths;
  if (testFile) {
    fullPaths = paths.server + 'tests/' + testFile;
  } else {
    fullPaths = serverUnitTestFiles;
  }
  var dbConnectionModulePath = paths.server + 'tests/db-connection.js';
  var dbConnection = gulp.src(dbConnectionModulePath, { read: false });
  var tests = gulp.src(fullPaths, { read: false });
  return series(dbConnection, tests)
      .pipe(mocha({ reporter: 'nyan' }));
});
```

And here is the db-connection.js module:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    connection = mongoose.connection,
    dbName = 'learnMongo';

before(function (done) {
  connection.on('error', console.error);
  connection.once('open', function () {
    done();
  });
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/' + dbName);
});

after(function (done) {
  connection.close(done);
});
```